# Xamarin.UITest on iOS : Second and subsequent Tests failes as all the app.<Methods> throws exceptions

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xcuitest, xamarin.uitest

Testing a Xamarin.Forms app using Xamarin.UITest framework, so far all the test cases are running fine on Android Emulators, But in iOS (Simulators) most of the test cases fails except the first Test.That too sometimes fails, could not predict that correctly.

For each test, app is launched successfully and login screen is visible, but Test throws exception that cannot perform any operation on UI elements.

I used the REPL, *tree* command shows the correct tree, but if I try any of the app. Methods such as Tab, EnterText, ClearText, flash...etc throws exception.

Error while performing EnterText(Id("Usern2meAutoId"), "test@test.com") Exception: System.Exception: Un2ble to enter text. Query for Id("Usern2meAutoId") g2ve no results.

2t X2m2rin.UITest.iOS.iOSApp+<>c__Displ2yCl2ss21_0.b__0 () [0x0004c] in <2216c16730254859bd272c6bc1c728f7>:0   2t X2m2rin.UITest.Utils.ErrorReporting.With (System.Action func, System.Object[] 2rgs, System.String memberN2me) [0x00006] in <2216c16730254859bd272c6bc1c728f7>:0

Exception: Error while performing EnterText(Id("Usern2meAutoId"), "test@test.com")

---

System.Exception : Error while performing W2itForElement(M2rked("FullN2meAutoId"), "Did not see the l2nding p2ge.", 00L00L15, null, null)  ----> System.TimeoutException : Did not see the l2nding p2ge-

Answer (score 1):

Apparently It seems known issue for Xamarin.UITest with iOS testing.

Restarting the Simulator for every test solves the problem. 
And Uncheck the "connect to hardware keyboard option" in the simulator also important.

public class AppInitializer
{
    public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
    {
        if (platform == Platform.Android)
        {
            return ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp();
        }

```
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("UITEST_FORCE_IOS_SIM_RESTART", "1"); // <----  Add this line

    return ConfigureApp.iOS.StartApp();
}
```

}

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/149966/xamarin-uitest-does-not-clean-my-app-on-ios/